# SQLAllocHandle is throwing SQL_ERROR for DB2 V9.7

Tags: c++, db2

We have upgraded our machines to 64 bit from 32 bit. The DB2 is also upgraded from 8.1 to 9.7.

Our source codes (C++) are compiled in 32 bit in 64 bit machine. We used `-m32` option for this.

But after fixing all our compilation issues, while executing, the application is throwing error in `SQLAllocHandle` function.

When debugged, we identified it is throwing `SQL_ERROR`.

Is there a constraint for DB29.7 and 32 bit code? What could be the possible cause for this issue? Whether the DB2 installation need any additional parameters to support 32 bit code?

Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You probably need to make sure you are using a 32-bit DB2 client instance with your 32-bit program.

Comment: Our DB2 installation has folders lib32 and lib64 inside the V9.7 folder. Our code refers the lib32 folder (Makefiles are modified for that).

Comment: That may be the case, but to what binaries and shared libs do the environment variables point? It doesn't matter what's in your makefile, what matters is the runtime configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which OS are you using? In a Linux 64 bits, I know that it is necessary to install the Linux header files for 32 and 64 bits for cases like yours. In this way, DB2 can call a already compiled application for 32 bits.

Did you check the prerequisites of the installation before installing db2? db2prereqs

Comment: We are using Redhat 6.3. We do have lib32 and lib64 folders in DB2 V9.7 folder. The Makefiles are modified to refer lib32 folder. I will cross-verify the installation again with db2prereqs.